# Finding SUM based on a Condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In my table in MYSQL have category 1-12 and under category question 001-300, a have create sum from category 6+7+8+9+10 example

    `category question correct
       1          1       3
       1          2       9
       2          1       8
       6          1       2
       7          1       9
      12         10       3`

result
    `category question correct
       1          1        3
       1          2        9
       2          1        8
       6+7        1       11
       12        10        3`

How to do it?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense.  Where does the second line for "12" come from?  Are you trying to modify the data or just query it?

Comment: Sorry, error in copy.

Comment: This kind of problem *can* be indicative of poor design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` to achieve what you want.

Sample output :[image]

Here is [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cb86/1)

```
  SELECT *
  FROM table_name WHERE `category`<6
  UNION

  SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(`category` SEPARATOR '+')) AS category,
          (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `question` SEPARATOR '+')) AS question,
          (SUM(`correct`)) AS correct
  FROM table_name WHERE category BETWEEN 6 AND 10

  UNION

  SELECT *
  FROM table_name WHERE `category`>10
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `group by` with a `case` statement:

```
select (case when min(category) = max(category) then min(category)
             else group_concat(category order by category separator '+')
        end) as category,
       question, sum(correct) as correct
from mytable
group by (case when category in (6, 7, 8, 9, 10) then -1 else category end),
         question;
```

Actually, this can be simplified to:

```
select group_concat(category order by category separator '+') as category,
       question, sum(correct) as correct
from mytable
group by (case when category in (6, 7, 8, 9, 10) then -1 else category end),
         question;
```